# why bash source command executes any leftover parameters in $*

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am on SLES 11 SP3, using GNU bash 3.2.51. I have noticed an unusual behavior when doing `source filename` - it executes anything handing in command line args `$*`.

file f1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#this is only a test driver
echo FYI PWD=$PWD
./f2.sh "$*"
```

file f2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#this is the application script
echo args in f2.sh were $*
```

File f3.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#this is the real driver code
echo FYI PWD=$PWD
source ~/.bashrc
./f2.sh "$*"
```

When I execute `f1.sh cat f2.sh` I get the following which seems OK

```
/tmp> ./f1.sh cat f1.sh
FYI PWD=/tmp
args were cat f1.sh
```

But when I execute `f3.sh cat f2.sh` I get, *very unexpectedly*

```
/tmp> ./f3.sh cat f1.sh
cat: f1.sh: No such file or directory
cat: f1.sh: No such file or directory
FYI PWD=/usr/app/DB/DB00
./f3.sh: line 4: ./f2.sh: No such file or directory
```

In the end I decided to modify `f3.sh` to `shift` away any remaining `$*` values before executing `source ~/.bashrc`

```
#!/bin/bash
#this is the real driver code
echo FYI PWD=$PWD
cmd="$*"
while shift; do true; done #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< get rid of hanging args
source ~/.bashrc
./f2.sh ${cmd}
```

but I don't know why it works that way. Perhaps someone more knowledgeable can explain exactly what's happening. (maybe there is an option for it) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Probably better to use `$@` instead.

Comment: Your example doesn’t show that `source` uses `$*` but that `source ~/.bashrc` does which is very different. Check your `~/.bashrc` for anything that could use `$*`.

Comment: You are sure the sourcing is doing it? Does sourcing other files have the same behavior? What is changing `PWD` in `f3.sh`? What does your `.bashrc` contain? Does it operate on positional parameters at all?

Comment: The only odd thing about @bfontaine's suggestion is that the error messages (seem to) occur before the `echo` statement, which occurs before the `source` command. This could just be a side effect of merging standard output and standard error, though; determining what `.bashrc` might be doing with the positional parameters is a good first step.

Comment: `set --` is a simpler way to clear the positional parameters.

Comment: @dinesh, you are inconsistent with your use of quotes: use them everywhere, except if you know exactly when to omit them.

Comment: @bfontaine and all, found it! thanks a lot for the pointers. I had lent my script to someone else who had a lot of other stuff going on in their .bashrc including use of $@. Nothing to do with `source`

Comment: @Dinesh I wrote it as an answer with a detailed example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` doesn’t uses `$*`; but sourcing another script executes it in the same context and thus makes `$*` available for it. Here the `~/.bashrc` is probably using the script arguments with either `$*` or `$@`.

Here is an example with `origin.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "       args before: $*"
source ./script.sh
echo "        args after: $*"
```

`script.sh`:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "args in the script: $*"
# shift the list twice
shift
shift
```

Executing `./origin.sh` shows:

```
$ ./origin.sh foo bar qux
       args before: foo bar qux
args in the script: foo bar qux
        args after: qux
```

This confirms that `script.sh` has access to `$*`, can use it and modify it.

Now if I change `origin.sh` to execute `script.sh` instead of sourcing it, it’ll get evaluated in another shell and won’t have access to `origin.sh`’s `$*`:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo "       args before: $*"
./script.sh
echo "        args after: $*"
```

The result:

```
./origin.sh foo bar qux
       args before: foo bar qux
args in the script:
        args after: foo bar qux
```